# How do I iterate over two lists of dictionaries to find a common key-value pair?

Tags: python

I have two lists that, each containing a couple of dictionaries:
How could I check if there is a common key-value pair in both dictionaries ?

**Example list of dictionaries - 1**

```
[
    {
        'id':'1',
        'name':'a'
    },
    {
        'id':'2',
        'name':'c'
    }
]
```

**Example list of dictionaries - 2**

```
[
    {
        'id':'4',
        'name':'d'
    },
    {
        'id':'2',
        'name':'a'
    }
]
```

In the above example, there is a common key-value pair: 'name':'a'

How can I check if a similar match exists ?

Comment: you have two lists that contain two dictionaries btw

Comment: one easy option would be to flatten each list so that each index contains only the `name` value, use `set` and check for intersections

Comment: @luigigi very useful comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
len(
    set.intersection(
        {x["name"] for x in list_1},
        {x["name"] for x in list_2},
    )
) > 0
```

...assuming you have the lists assigned to variables `list_1` and `list_2`.

Comment: This is checking only name key. What about id key

Comment: You can replace the key name with anything you wish. Just change "name" for "id".

Comment: Thank you man, it works! Anyway, I just need "name". I was wrong in my example: if "name" is the same also "id" is the same. I edited my question.